# Select last item for each unique column value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table containing message logs. Each conversation has a conversation ID.

I want to select distinct conversation IDs, and for each of them, find the latest message with that conversation ID and join it into the row.

This is what I tried but it doesn't add any data into the table except the two columns (`conversationId` and `id`). I want to get all columns from that table for each row with the latest

```
SELECT 
  logs.conversationId, 
  -- latest message id
  MAX(logs.id) AS id
  FROM [dbo].[Logs] AS logs

  -- trying to get the remaining columns for the last message with that conversation ID
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Logs] AS logs2 ON logs.id = logs2.id

  WHERE 
    -- only conversations for last month
    logs.timestamp >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())

  GROUP BY logs.conversationId
```

When I try to add another column into `SELECT`, I get the error saying I need to add that column into the `GROUP BY` clause. But that causes the statement to run for an extremely long time, over 20 seconds for just a few dozen rows in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()` function

```
select * 
from (
    select *, 
           row_number() over(partition by conversationId order by id desc) as rn 
    from logs 
) as t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

First get max log id per conversion from logs and then apply left join:

```
select * from 
(SELECT 
  logs.conversationId, 
  MAX(logs.id) AS id
  FROM [dbo].[Logs] AS logs group by logs.conversationId)a
left join [dbo].[Logs] AS logs2 ON a.id = logs2.id and a.conversationid=logs.conversationid
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subquery in `where` to make it.

```
select * 
from logs t 
where t.id = (
    SELECT MAX(tt.id)
    from logs tt
    WHERE tt.conversationId = t.conversationId
    GROUP BY tt.conversationId
)
```

**Note**

if you make index in `id` might be faster than `row_number` version